# Rails 3.1, RSpec - failing but page loads fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am writing some specs and the following is failing but the page /menus/1 is loading fine in a browser. This is a port of a php app and is first time I've used RSpec. Any thoughts as to why it might not be working.

The error is:

```
1) MenusController GET 'show' should be succesful
  Failure/Error: get :show, :id => 1
  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
  Couldn't find MenuHeader with id=1
  # ./app/controllers/menus_controller.rb:18:in `show'
  # ./spec/controllers/menus_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

but that specific MenuHeader does exist based upon all normal criteria (console, mysql, browser). I'm 99% sure I have a mistake in my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MenusController do
  describe "GET 'show'" do
     it "should be succesful" do
       get :show, :id => 1
       response.should be_success
     end
  end
end
```

here is the menus_controller.rb

```
def show
  @menu_header_data=MenuHeader.find(params[:id])


  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    # format.json { render json: @menu } to do
  end
end
```

thx

Comment: Aside: Do you have a test for "get show with non-existent id should fail" ?

Comment: Are you running this against a test database? Are you using fixtures or factories?

Comment: running against test database with data in it

Comment: can you post the code for `app/controllers/menus_controller.rb:18`

Comment: `rake db:test:prepare` and confirm that the data is actually there from the console in the test env.

Answer (score 4):

When testing a controller with Rspec or TestUnit I would use a Factory or Fixture to pass the id rather than setting up a test database with data.  It's better to test with something like:

Using [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) (My Recommendation but everyone has their own tastes):

```
describe MenusController do
  describe "GET 'show'" do
     it "should be succesful" do
       get :show, :id => Factory(:menu).id
       response.should be_success
     end
  end
end
```

The test is mainly just to make sure the controller responds properly when provided valid data, and using Factories or Fixtures is much less brittle.  It will become a pain to maintain your test suite if it's based on hard data like fixtures or a db backup, and that could ultimately lead to you giving up on Test Driven Development rather than embracing it.

Comment: `Factory.define :menu do |menu|
  menu.name "My Menu Name"
  menu.id 1
end`